# 2 пакета с одинаковым названием Maven

Tags: java, maven, package

Имеет Maven проект, где в pom имеются зависимости:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpos</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jpos</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpos</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

мне нужно использовать методы из `org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg`
так уж получилось, что пакет `ru.company` включает в себе `org.jpos`[image: как на картинке]

если я в `pom` укажу только `ru.company`, то все работает как нужно, но мне нужен еще и другой пакет. 
Как бы мне решить данную проблему?

p.s. так как один пакет включает в себе другой, то можно использовать именно этот пакет. но хотелось бы получить ответ как быть в данной ситуации

Comment: Загуглите Dependency Exclusions maven, похоже на то, что Вам нужно?

Comment: @MrFylypenko да, подходит. спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно исключить с помощью Maven [Dependency Exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html), примерно должно быть так:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>ru.company</groupId>
      <artifactId>jpos</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.8.2</version>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.jpos</groupId>
              <artifactId>jpos</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jpos</groupId>
      <artifactId>jpos</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.0</version>
  </dependency>
```